# Subscriber is not being added to Publication List

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Can someone tell me what I am missing? The All Subscriber Status is being updated. But the Subscriber is not being added to a Publication List.

```
    SET @sub = CreateObject("Subscriber")
    SET @client = CreateObject("ClientID")
    SetObjectProperty(@client, "ID", @mid)
    SetObjectProperty(@sub, "Client", @client)
    SetObjectProperty(@sub, "EmailAddress", @email)
    SetObjectProperty(@sub, "SubscriberKey", @email)
    SetObjectProperty(@sub, "Status", "Active")
    FOR @i = 1 TO ROWCOUNT(@listRS) DO
        SET @listRow = ROW(@listRS, @i)
        Set @listId = FIELD(@listRow, 1)
        SET @list = CreateObject("SubscriberList")
        SetObjectProperty(@list, "ID", @listId)
        SetObjectProperty( @list, "IDSpecified", "true" )
        SetObjectProperty(@list, "Status", "Active")
        SetObjectProperty(@list, "StatusSpecified", "true")
        AddObjectArrayItem(@sub, "Lists", @list)
    NEXT @i
    SET @statusCode = InvokeUpdate(@sub, @statusMsg, @errorCode)
```

Comment: I have tried to add SetObjectProperty(@list, "Action", "create") after the StatusSpecified line (from this article https://help.exacttarget.com/en/technical_library/web_service_guide/technical_articles/managing_subscribers_on_lists/) and still the subscriber is not being added????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to add the **SaveOption** and **CreateOptions** and change from **InvokeUpdate** to **InvokeCreate** to get this to work.

```
SET @sub = CreateObject("Subscriber")
SET @client = CreateObject("ClientID")
SetObjectProperty(@client, "ID", @mid)
SetObjectProperty(@sub, "Client", @client)
SetObjectProperty(@sub, "EmailAddress", @email)
SetObjectProperty(@sub, "SubscriberKey", @email)
SetObjectProperty(@sub, "Status", "Active")
FOR @i = 1 TO ROWCOUNT(@listRS) DO
    SET @listRow = ROW(@listRS, @i)
    Set @listId = FIELD(@listRow, 1)
    SET @list = CreateObject("SubscriberList")
    SetObjectProperty(@list, "ID", @listId)
    SetObjectProperty( @list, "IDSpecified", "true" )
    SetObjectProperty(@list, "Status", "Active")
    SetObjectProperty(@list, "StatusSpecified", "true")
    AddObjectArrayItem(@sub, "Lists", @list)
NEXT @i

    SET @saveOpt = CreateObject("SaveOption")
    SetObjectProperty(@saveOpt, "SaveAction", "UpdateAdd")
    SetObjectProperty(@saveOpt, "PropertyName", "*")

    SET @createOpts = CreateObject("CreateOptions")
    AddObjectArrayItem(@createOpts, "SaveOptions", @saveOpt)

    SET @statusCode = InvokeCreate(@sub, @statusMsg, @errorCode, @createOpts)
```